# Exception error while compiling game code

Tags: java, exception

I am a complete beginner at Java, and I tried running the following code:

```
package Happily.Insane.Rain;


import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public static int width = 300;
        public static height = width / 16 * 9;
        public static int scale = 3;

        private Thread thread;
        private JFrame frame;
        private boolean running = false;

        public Game() {
                Dimension size = new Dimension (width*scale, height*scale);
                setPreferredSize(size);

                frame = new JFrame();
        }

        public synchronized void start() {
                running = true;
                thread = new Thread (this, "Display");
                thread.start();
        }

        public synchronized void stop() {
                running = false;
                try {
                        thread.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        public void run() {
                while (running) {
                        System.out.println("Running...");
                }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                Game game = new Game();
                game.frame.setResizable(false);
                game.frame.setTitle("Rain");
                game.frame.add(game);
                game.frame.pack();
                game.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                game.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                game.frame.setVisible(true);

                game.start();
        }

}
```

Had the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

        at Happily.Insane.Rain.Game.main(Game.java:47)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why wouldn't you tell us what line 47 is....?

Comment: @MohammadS. Actually, the error is **not** in line 47. It is in line 13: http://ideone.com/qaGVsA

Comment: You are not only a beginner in Java, but also a beginner in programming concepts. What was your intention to write a class that extends Canvas and also implements Runnable, while additionally instantiating a JFrame when being constructed? Brrr.... (Not to mention the compiler errors, you really should read before executing that.)

Comment: @ComFreek I know that.  I'm just wondering why he wouldn't tell us that line (or give us some sort of direction on where he thinks the error is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not specify the type of the static variable `height`:

```
public static height = width / 16 * 9;
// ----------^
```

It should be an integer:

```
public static int height = width / 16 * 9;
```

---

In future posts, please highlight the affected line. Additionally, we are not a give-us-problems-we-will-solve-them-all system. Invest some own effort, do some researches and *then* come to us and ask a question.

Comment: Ok I'll remember that, I am only just beginning to learn it, I realise now that it was a silly question.